# New USB C MacBook - status light for charging without turning computer on

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging, touch-bar

For the new MacBook Pro with Touch Bar (and also the old tiny MacBook) that uses USB-C charging - is there something like a "status light" to see if your MacBook is charging (or full) without turning the screen on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No light is provided on Apple cables, adapters or the MacBook.

The device makes a quiet charge sound when you connect the USB cord, so unplug and listen for that sound when you reconnect the charging cable.

It is similar to the sound made when an iPad or iPhone connects.

For those that prefer light to sound, some docks and adapters have a charging indicator, and probably more will follow suit.

- https://www.moshi.com/usb-c-multiport-adapter#silver
- [usb c to usb a cable with charging led](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01FHSKVNK)
- [Usb c to usb a adapter with charging indicator](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015Z7XE0A)

Comment: how quiet does your room have to be to be able to hear that sound? what does it sound like?

Comment: the moshi seems to be a peripheral adapter and not a charger?

Comment: The sound is pretty quiet so you might miss it, but it is exactly the same sound you hear when you charge an iphone or ipad. I realise it is not exactly what you need but I can't find any cables with the functionality yet, but they will come in due time.

Comment: @ina You are right - mocha sits between the charger and your Mac so that it can light up when charging. I don't know if it's a charge light or a power light, so be sure you can return it if you can't determine that before buying.

Comment: i regret buying this 2018 pro. look how sad your answer hears

Answer (score 1):

This adaptor looks amazing! 30char

https://www.moshi.com/en/product/integra-usb-c-charge-cable-with-smart-led/jet-silver

Comment: website shady as hell. can't trust them